# A Ukrainian idiom meaning "on one's last legs"

Tags: переклад, from-english, фразеологізми

I'm looking for a Ukrainian idiom which would mean the same as the English "[on one's last legs](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-ones-last-legs)." Here is the context:

> By then, the Soviet Union was **on its last legs**; it would be dissolved the following year."

Is there an idiom which could be used like this? If there isn't, a phrase which would sound natural would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible idiomatic expression: 
*бути при останньому подиху* 
(literally: to be on the last breath).

Comment: I think, out of all the great idioms shared here, this idiom is the most stylistically suitable for the kind of translation I’m doing. Thank you and thank you everybody!

Answer (score 8):

> [Довідник англійських, німецьких та українських ідіом і виразів — 2005](https://e2u.org.ua/s?highlight=on&w=on+one%27s+last+legs)
>         
>         (Шерік А.Д., Савічук В.Я., Старко В.Ф.)
>
> ---
>
> **to be on one’s last legs**
>
> auf dem letzten Loch pfeifen, nicht mehr lange mitmachen
>
> бути смертельно втомленим, вмирати, *дихати на ладан*

---

> [**(6) На ла́дан (*рідко* на часни́к) ди́хати:**](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22441&page=767)
>
> 1. бути безнадійно хворим, близьким до смерті; помирати.
>
>    *[Флорентієць:] Він вже старий. Він дихає на ладан* (М. Костомаров); *[Тарас:] Багато вже не стало тих, що воювали вмісті [разом] ви!.. Один Кадило ще живий, та й той на ладан дише* (І. Карпенко-Карий); *Знає толк на травах [знахарка]. Колись мій батько на ладан дихав, а вона дала йому настойку на якомусь корені – і пішов старий* (М. Стельмах); *Давно уже говорили, що Лисун [дід] на часник дише, а він усе хрипів у землянці своїй* (В. Дрозд);
> 2. бути зношеним; розвалюватися, розпадатися від довгого користування.
>
>    *А в лаві колія стара на ладан просто дише. От і виходить – на-гора півнорми і не більше* (П. Дорошко);
> 3. бути близьким до припинення свого існування.
>
>    ***Австрія на ладан дихає…** Скрізь нас молотять, аж пір'я летить* (С. Масляк, пер. з тв. Я. Гашека);

Comment: The question has been asked in English, so this post would benefit if it had at least a brief English translation/explanation of idioms mentioned within.

Answer (score 6):

**Дихати на ладан** (lit. *to breathe on a Frankincense*) or [**дбати про ладан та домовину**](http://sum.in.ua/s/ladan) (*to care of Frankincense and a coffin*).

[Ладан](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD) or [Frankincense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankincense) is an aromatic incense used in Orthodox Christian churches to anoint a dead man during a memorial service.

Hence, saying that something is "{already} breathing on a Frankincense" means it is already half way in a coffin.

Also, one can say **однією ногою у труні** which is literally "one leg in a coffin".

Comment: Шчо ж, ти швидше.

Answer (score 5):

- [На останню прясти. Прясти на тонку (на тонке).](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53407/360801.html)

  > 1. Бути тяжко хворим; бути при смерті.
  >
  >    Не забув Клим про хвору Соломію. Вже ні за що не береться, на тонке пряде (М. Рудь).
  > 2. Ставати непридатним для використання.
  >
  >    — У тебе вже кофта на тонку пряде, а у Василя сорочка розлізлася (З журналу).
- [Вали́тися (па́дати) від ві́тру.](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53394/356206.html)

  > Бути знесиленим, дуже виснаженим, слабим. А як вийду за ворота, — Од вітру валюся (П. Чубинський);
- Тільки тінь з його осталась.
- Не їсть — лише дивиться.
- Уже на нього собаки давно часник товчуть.

Comment: Цікаво, що [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/prjasty) дає інше значення для _на тонку прясти_ — «хитрувати» (не розділяючи його з _тонко прясти_). Але в цьому разі моя довіра до СУМ-11 менша (тим більше, що трактовка _тонко прясти_ теж відрізняється: у СУМ-11, як я вже казав, «хитрувати», в інших словниках — «робити щось не так, як слід, нерозумно, необдумано»). (Зате всі словники згодні щодо _на останню прясти_, яке ще в жодній відповіді не згадано.)

Comment: The question has been asked in English, so this post would benefit if it had at least a brief English translation/explanation of idioms mentioned within.

Comment: Дякую! А що таке тонка взагалі?

Comment: @Enguroo I believe here *тонка* means *thin*. Please, look [here](http://sum.in.ua/s/tonkyj) at the end of the second clause in bold.

Comment: @Yola, I believe, Enguroo asks about the *implicit noun* assosiated with the adjective *тонка/тонке*.

Comment: @bytebuster I'm not sure how to answer this comment then, I believe it is worthy of separate question.

Comment: Maybe. But on the other hand, the answer must be "useful" (see the tooltip on upvote/downvote buttons). That's why I suggested to research your answer with some explanation of idioms.